# Lexical declaration used as right-hand side value in if statement

Tags: perl

Compare case 1:

```
if (defined (my $a_var = $h->{a})) {
    # .. do some calculations with $a_var 
}
```

and case 2:

```
if (defined $h->{a}) {
    my $a_var = $h->{a};
    # .. do some calculations with $a_var 
}
```

what would be best programming practice, to use case 1 or case 2?

I see that for case 1, I do not have to repeat `$h->{a}` twice. But it will also make the lexical variable `$a_var` (unintentionally) available in following `elsif` and `else` blocks..

Another question: Where is this usage of declaration as right-hand side value of another expression documented at [perldoc.perl.org](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl.html) ?

(For example, statements like `my $a = (my $b = (my $c = 3));` are perfectly valid..)

Comment: Although it doesn't make much difference in your example, the first form is more convenient than the second when used in the conditional of a `while` loop. In fact, this pattern is common enough that I would call it an idiom. For example, `while (<STDIN>) { }` is equivalent to `while (defined($_ = <STDIN>)) { }`.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Yes, case 1 seems to be more convenient in `while` loops..I agree. The problem with `if` statements, seems to be that the lexical variable propagates into following `elsif` and `else` blocks.. usually this is not desired, and could lead to confusing code that are difficult to debug/read for others..

Comment: I don't think that behavior is confusing. Note that [the same thing applies](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Private-Variables-via-my%28%29) to `until` and `continue` blocks attached to `while` and `foreach` loops, e.g. while (my $line = <>) { $line = lc $line; } continue { print $line; }` There's a similar example for `if/elsif/else` in `perlsub` in the section I linked to.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Thanks for the link, that was the documentation I was looking for, but couldn't find.. Maybe you are right.. if the user knows about the scoping rules that applies, it should not be confusing.. I was first thinking it would be logical that the scope of the variable should be confined only to the `if` part, and not extend to the  `else` parts, but maybe that was not so logical after all in retrospect :)

Answer (score 1):

[`perldoc perlsub`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Private-Variables-via-my%28%29) says:

> The `my` is simply a modifier on something you might assign to.

That is, anywhere you have `$foo` you can also write `my $foo` (except for quoted constructs, of course).

---

As for your first question, I have no opinion on that.

Comment: Great, I was searching in `perlsyn` and `perldata` and `perlintro`, I wouldn't think it was in `perlsub` :)

Comment: I found it by starting at [`perldoc -f my`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/my.html)

Comment: When I type `perldoc -f my` I get this output: http://pastebin.com/9X5WXdE4 . It is not mentioned as far as I can see..

Comment: @HåkonHægland  'See "Private Variables via my()" in perlsub for details' - which is what I linked.